# Laravel SSH - create tmux session

Tags: laravel, ssh, tmux

I have the following:

```
\Config::set('remote.connections.runtime.host', $server->server_ip);

$commands = [
    'tmux'
];

\SSH::run($commands, function($line) {
    echo $line.PHP_EOL;
});

dd();
```

This outputs the following error:

> open terminal failed: not a terminal

Is it possible to create a tmux session this way?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing you can do to make this work with Laravel SSH. However, Laravel's SSH component uses [phpseclib SSH](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/ssh/intro.html) internally which is more flexible when used directly.

Now I'm assuming you're trying to create a `tmux` session to start some process that you want to continue running in the background after the SSH connection has ended. The good part is that since phpseclib is a dependency of Laravel SSH it's already there so there's no need to install it. I'm not very familiar with `tmux` and it's options, but I can offer a solution that uses `screen` instead:

```php
use \phpseclib\Net\SSH2;
use \phpseclib\File\ANSI;

$ssh = new SSH2('host');
$ansi = new ANSI();

if ($ssh->login('username', 'password')) {
    // The command below will start a screen
    // session and automatically detach it
    $ssh->write("screen -m -d -S processes top\n");

    // You can include the lines below to see the
    // output of the write command converted to HTML
    $ansi->appendString($ssh->read());
    echo $ansi->getScreen();
}
```

This creates a new automatically detached `screen` session named `processes` and runs the `top` command in it. To connect to the session you can simply run this in your console:

```
ssh username@host -t "screen -r processes"
```

This will reattach the `processes` session so you can see what's going on. Of course you could adapt this to use `tmux` if that's you're preference.